# Export customers List in Zencart

Tags: cpanel, zen-cart

I have a client that wants to switch from ZenCart to other e-commerce platform. How can I export the customer information in Zencart?

1. Is there any plugin available in Zencart to export the customer's data?
2. Do we have to ask the client for C-panel or any databases
3. Through C-panel, can we download the customer's data? If yes, please provide any article for that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!